# how to get varying modal content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to get the varying modal content but I am not sure where I am going wrong as I am new to JavaScript

My Code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="sampleText" >testData</a>



        <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" id="exampleModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
                     <form>
     <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              </form>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
              var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
              var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
              var modal = $(this)
              modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
              modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
            })
        </script>
```

My aim is to display the "sampleText" in the input text box. But I dont get it. I am only getting empty box.
Also is there a way to display a list of strings in the input box.?? 
Sorry if my question is very basic.
S

Comment: To display a list of values I have tried something like this:
<script>
 $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $('[data-target="#exampleModal"]')
    var recipient= button.data('whatever') 
    var modal = $(this)
    for(s : recipient)
       modal.find('.modal-body input').text(s + '\n')   
  })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element with class of `.modal-body` in your markup, the selector should be `.modal-content input`.

```
modal.find('.modal-content input').val(recipient);
```

If by a list of strings you mean  *-separated values, you can define an array and join the elements using `Array.prototype.join` method:

```
var list = ['an', 'array'];
var string = list.join('glue');
// ...
modal.find('.modal-content input').val(string);
```

Comment: Thanks. I made this correction - modal.find('.modal-content input').val(recipient); Still not getting the right output. This statement is not correct I guess-- var recipient = button.data('whatever') as I am using<a> and not <button>

Comment: @HariniSridhar You are welcome! Can you reproduce the problem? It works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tv2un8yj/).

Comment: `button` is just an identifier, it doesn't make any difference, what matters is it refers to the jQuerified `relatedTarget` of the event object.

Comment: Yes. It is working in the fiddle. But not working for me even when I copy and paste the same. That javascript is not being called at all I guess

Comment: 'New message to undefined' is what I am getting:(

Comment: @HariniSridhar What exactly is `undefined` in your code?

Comment: modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient) --- this line is intended to display 'New message to sampleText' instead it is displaying 'New message to undefined' and the 'Recipient:' field is just empty.

Comment: @HariniSridhar That's probably because `$(event.relatedTarget)` returns an empty collection or refers to another element which doesn't have `data-whatever` attribute, can you use `$('[data-target="#exampleModal"]')`  instead  of `$(event.relatedTarget)`?

Comment: var button = $(event.currentTarget) did not work either. Is there a way to do this? my aim is to display a list of names in the modal-content by iteration. I started with a small example of displaying one string. But that if not successful

Comment: @HariniSridhar Yes, the `currentTarget` property of the event object refers to the modal itself. Please read my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. It really helped. Now I am facing small difficulties with iterating over a list. This is what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/tv2un8yj/5/ .. But  could display only the last element in the array list

Comment: @HariniSridhar You are very welcome. `text` overrides the current textContent of the element. You could use the `join` method: http://jsfiddle.net/kwrcxf2g/